# False alarm in CLANG 3.42

Tags: c++, clang

CLANG gives a false alarm for vector null reference

I am running CLANG version 3.4.2 with the following command:

```
clang -std=c++11 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700 -D_BSD_SOURCE -I/home/user/projects/src -I/home/user/projects/extern/include -I/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/ -I/usr/include/mysql/ -Wall -Wextra -Wunreachable-code -Werror -Wformat=2 -Wunused -Wpedantic -Wconversion -isystem /home/user/projects/extern/include/bitcoin/  -g --analyze --analyzer-output text
```

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

void DummyFunction(void)
{
    std::vector<std::string>  dummy_vec;
    std::string  sharonStr ("test");
    dummy_vec.push_back(sharonStr);
    printf("%s", dummy_vec.at(0).c_str());
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string>  vec;
    std::string  str ("test1");

    // Removing this line also makes the warning disappear
    vec.push_back(str);
    printf("%s", vec.at(0).c_str());
}
```

When the code is as above -- i get the following warning:

```
/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.5/../../../../include/c++/4.8.5/bits/stl_vector.h:771:9: 
warning: Returning null reference
      { return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n); }
        ^
/home/itai/tmp.cpp:10:22: note: Calling 'vector::at'
        printf("%s", dummy_vec.at(0).c_str());
                     ^~~~~~~~~
/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.5/../../../../include/c++/4.8.5/bits/stl_vector.h:813:9: note: Calling 'vector::operator[]'
        return (*this)[__n]; 
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.5/../../../../include/c++/4.8.5/bits/stl_vector.h:771:9: note: Returning null reference
      { return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n); }
```

However, if i:

- delete the DummyFunction (which isn't invoked anywhere) -- the warning goes away.
- delete the "vec.push_back(str);" line from main() the warning also goes away.

Comment: The error messages you show doesn't match the code you show. The `printf` call in the code is not on line 15 as reported in the error.

Comment: Also Clang version 3.4 is very old by now, as is the GCC C++ library (which seems to be used) version 4.8. There could be bugs in both that have been solved in later versions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude -- sorry for the mismatch in the line numbers...
I removed some comments when i posted it here. -- fixed in edit.


Regarding the version -- i know.. but i am trying to avoid upgrading the CLANG version for now

Comment: Interesting a somewhat identical error can be seen on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ABNJnH) using clang 3.4.1. With clang 3.5 the warning is gone.
Most interesting is, that the exact same code in main and DummyFunction creates different warnings. I would vote for a compiler (or analyzer) bug

Comment: @MofX -- if i comment out this line: "vec.push_bach(str)" -- the error is also gone

Comment: The error message still doesn't match the code. According to the error message, `printf("%s", vec.at(0).c_str());` is line 10, but in your code this looks like like 19, while line 10 uses `dummy_vec`. Which of these lines is the error on?

Comment: @interjay - you are right... so sorry :(  -- fixed

Comment: The question is.... - does anyone know of some WA i can do with the current CLANG version, instead of upgrading it?

Comment: It's a warning you say? How about explicitly suppressing it?

Comment: @JVApen - 
I have this in multiple places in the code... i guess i can start suppressing them one by one... if all else fails - might go for this.. .thanks

Comment: Or suppress it completely via the command line